# c# how to check multiple values in web browser?

Tags: c#, web, browser, getattribute

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span"))
        {
            if (elem.GetAttribute("item-price hidden") == "$0.11")
            {

            }


        }

    }
```

I want to check if item price is $0.11,$0.12,$0.13..etc..How do I check multiple values?

Comment: First , you need to create a list of price, then you can check if elem.GetAttribute("item-price hidden") exists in that list using C#. 

@Avadoto

Comment: How many values do you want to check? You can use a list/array to compare against.

Comment: can you help me do it?

Comment: I want to check from 0.11 to 0.5 so thats 40 values